Reuse SQL Column Lists?
I keep running into situations where I have to repeat the same column list over and over and over again. How can I avoid this code duplication?
SELECT a,b,c as foo,d,e,f,g,h,i,j as bar
FROM [fn_MyFunction](1)
UNION
SELECT a,b,c as foo,d,e,f,g,h,i,j as bar
FROM [fn_MyFunction](2)
UNION
SELECT a,b,c as foo,d,e,f,g,h,i,j as bar
FROM [fn_MyFunction](3)
UNION
SELECT a,b,c as foo,d,e,f,g,h,i,j as bar
FROM [fn_MyFunction](4)

I would like to eliminate this code duplication with something like  this.
@ColumnList = a,b,c as foo,d,e,f,g,h,i,j as bar
SELECT @ColumnList
FROM [fn_MyFunction](1)
UNION
SELECT @ColumnList
FROM [fn_MyFunction](2)
UNION
SELECT @ColumnList
FROM [fn_MyFunction](3)
UNION
SELECT @ColumnList
FROM [fn_MyFunction](4)


There is no easy way... SQL isn't intended to be DRY. Although you might question your design if you are pulling the same column list from many different objects.

In my actual query,I have a function that performs a complicated filter based on a handful of parameters, and there are a bunch of specific parameter combinations that have special business relevance, hence the long string of unions.

Why wouldn't you change your TVF to accept an integer list instead of a single int.

You could always use a sub-query e.g. select a, b, c from (select * from myfunction union all select * from myfunction). FYI you do know that UNION is slower than UNION ALL? Because UNION de-dups the data.

You can generate a list of values by using a subquery + VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4) construct and then cross apply them with the fn_MyFunction call

You can use a VALUES clause for the parameters, and then CROSS APPLY the function.
SELECT DISTINCT    -- UNION implies DISTINCT, did you mean UNION ALL??
  f.a, f.b,
  f.c as foo,
  f.d, f.e, f.f,
  f.g, f.h, f.i,
  f.j as bar
FROM (VALUES
    (1), (2), (3), (4)
) AS v(n)
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_MyFunction(v.n) AS f;

If the parameters come from an application then you can use a Table Valued Parameter. If they come from another table then you can join that straight in.
